# What is difference between group and user

Tags: 14.04

I am totally new to Ubuntu.
I just start to learn about Ubuntu.
So please help me to learn about Ubuntu.

Comment: Google? See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User is an account, either for real person or a daemon software. You can log in with your user account, or others using `su`.

Groups can be thought of as levels of privilege. A person who is part of a group can view or modify files belonging to that group, depending on the permissions of that file. User belonging to a group has privilleges of that group, for example - `sudo` groups lets you run software as super user.

Answer (score 4):

Users can be either people, meaning accounts tied to physical users, or accounts which exist for specific applications to use.
Groups are logical expressions of organization, tying users together for a common purpose. Users within a group can read, write, or execute files owned by that group.

Each user and group has a unique numerical identification number called a userid (UID) and agroupid (GID) respectively.
A user who creates a file is also the owner and group owner of that file. The file is assigned separate read, write, and execute permissions for the owner, the group, and everyone else. The file owner can be changed only by the root user as well as access permissions can be changed by both the root user and the owner of the file.

Source : http://www.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/110533/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-group-and-others-in-red-hat-linux-what-is-the-use-of-group-ownership-amp-user-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder/

Answer (score 2):

Multiple users can use privileges of a group. For example if a group has permission to read, write or execute one particular file or folder, or change one specific setting, all the users within that group will inherit this privilege.

You can find different kinds of privileges that a user or a group may have or not [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux/Unix, then the concept of permissions may be confusing. This Link will provide you with an explanation of what permissions are, how they work, and how to manage them. A number of examples will be provided to illustrate how to set and change permissions for both users and 
groups.

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups

Comment: Thank you for pointing the OP in the right direction, however it would be best if you outlined the information in the link because links can disappear, information can change, etc.